# local.xml not working in Magento 1.9.2.2 with RWD template

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I use Magento 1.9.2.2 with RWD package.
Seems that local.xml is not working.
If I copy the original catalog.xml to the directory with the local.xml, changes on catalog.xml are effectuated.

This is the code of the local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

<default>
    <!-- remove the language and store switcher and footer links blocks, we won't use them -->
    <remove name="store_language" />
    <remove name="store_switcher"/>
    <remove name="footer_links" />
</default>

<default>
<reference name="right">
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
<remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
<remove name="catalog.product.related" />
</reference>
</default>
```

Maybe I have placed the local.xml in the wrong place?

Hope anybody has a clue,
Els

[image: This is where I placed the local.xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close `layout` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <!--
    Default layout, loads most of the pages
    -->

    <default>
        <!-- remove the language and store switcher and footer links blocks, we won't use them -->
        <remove name="store_language" />
        <remove name="store_switcher"/>
        <remove name="footer_links" />
    </default>

    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
            <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
            <remove name="catalog.product.related" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks SeStro, but node was closed in original file. Just didn't copy the whole file. Sorry. Still have the same problem: all cache is cleared, as are the indexes, logged in and logged out. Problem still is: local.xml does not do anything. If I make the changes in My Custom Theme -> catalog.xml, it works fine. I remember I have read somewhere that local.xml is not working in 1.9.2.2. Is that correct? Is it OK to change the catalog.xml in My Custom Theme? Hope anybody has a clue.

Comment: Try to put 'remove' nodes to 'reference' node ('store_language' to 'header', 'store_switcher' and 'footer_links' to 'footer'). It sholud works, because 1.9.2.2 doesn't have any problems with local.xml files. If after all it will not work, you could do anything you want with 'catalog.xml' file in your custom template ;]

Comment: at SeStro: would you know what code I need in the local.xml in order to display a block with the filterable results (layered navigation) on the home page?

Comment: Update: I have used following code which works fine, but if I want to close the seconde <block>, it doesn't work anymore. How come anybody? `<!-- LAYERED NAVIGATION in left column-->
<reference name="left">
   <!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
   <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
   <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" /></block>
</reference>`